# How to import particle cache to a new scene?

Tags: particles, baking

I had a scene with hair dynamically positioned & baked to disk. When I saved the scene as the next iteration, that bake information is gone -- the hair is now at its base position. I tried doing a few google searches, and looked through the panel, but I just can't find a way to import frames from the previous scene to this one.

Anyone know how to do this?
Thanks much in advance!